# How to split MySQL coulm data into other columns?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to split  the 2nd data after 1st '|' to  different column but couldn't do it properly.

I have tried this following method to split up the column data but the  select substring method is not able to split the column properly.

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING_INDEX(btrim,'|',2) AS devicename,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(btrim,'|',1) AS brand
  FROM  fts_inventory
```

the following is the data from my table

```
btrim
----------------------------                                                                          
Samsung|Galaxy-J1|Sam-GalJ1                                                    
Samsung|Galaxy-J1|Sam-GalJ1                                                    
Samsung|Galaxy-J1|Sam-GalJ1                                                    
Samsung|Galaxy-J1|Sam-GalJ1                                                    
Samsung|Galaxy-J1|Sam-GalJ1                                                    
Samsung|Galaxy-J1|Sam-GalJ1                                                    
BBC|Brought-by-client|BROUGHT001                                               
Motorola|G4|Moto-G4L|on CDMA / LTE                                             
LTE-Sim|LTE-Sim|LTE-Sim pack                                                   
LTE-Sim|LTE-Sim|LTE-Sim pack
```

I want results like this in 2 separate columns:

```
devicename              brand
-------------------------------------    
 Galaxy-J1              Samsung                              
 Galaxy-J1              Samsung                              
 Galaxy-J1              Samsung                              
 Galaxy-J1              Samsung                              
 Galaxy-J1              Samsung                              
 Galaxy-J1              Samsung                              
 Brought-by-client          BBC  
 G4                    Motorola                             
 LTE-Sim                LTE-Sim                               
 LTE-Sim                LTE-Sim
```

but getting this :

```
devicename                      brand
---------------------------------------------    
Samsung|Galaxy-J1              Samsung                                  
Samsung|Galaxy-J1              Samsung                                  
Samsung|Galaxy-J1              Samsung                                  
Samsung|Galaxy-J1              Samsung                                  
Samsung|Galaxy-J1              Samsung                                  
Samsung|Galaxy-J1              Samsung                                  
BBC|Brought-by-client          BBC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

**Standard Query**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(btrim, '|', 1), '|', -1) as first,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(btrim, '|', 2), '|', -1) as second
       .....
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(btrim, '|', n), '|', -1) as nth
FROM fts_inventory;
```

**Exact Query**

```
  SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(btrim, '|', 2), '|', -1) as devicename,
         SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(btrim, '|', 1), '|', -1) as brand
  FROM fts_inventory;
```

Comment: @BaljotSingh Why dont you mark it as right answer then?

Comment: @BaljotSingh No, Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted", and by extension the question as "has an accepted answer". https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0):

In the syntax is `SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, count)`, using `-2` in the count will return your expected result.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(btrim, '|', -2), '|', 1) AS devicename,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(btrim,'|', 1) AS brand 
 FROM fts_inventory
```

Answer (score 0):

An option:

```sql
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(`der`.`btrim`, '|', -1) `devicename`,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(`der`.`btrim`, '|', 1) `brand`
FROM (
  SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(`btrim`, '|', 2) `btrim`
  FROM `fts_inventory`
) `der`;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1bf546ae6d0024d84a1c3df5f551abaf).